# Unbound DNS Default Response

Tags: dns

Using the current SVN of the Unbound DNS resolver. I would like to have a configuration where it will hand back a default IP? IE opendns if you attempt to resolve nonexistentdomain.com it will return the IP of their "not-found" web server.

Comment: for what queries?  All queries?  Just ones that don't get an answer from the real DNS?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Unbound.

Unbound can *override* external data, but it has no support in its `local-zone:` [configuration setting](http://www.unbound.net/documentation/unbound.conf.html)  for synthesising records for a domain only if the originally requested external data can't be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the local-zone but it's trivial with the python module hooks.

Performance on the other hand... :-)